# Необходимо написать программу,которая будет принимать строку и будет возвращать строку, содержащую следующий номер версии

Tags: python

```
# Написать функцию next_version, которая будет принимать строку (текущая версия программного обеспечения)
# и будет возвращать строку, содержащую следующий номер версии.
# Правила:
# все числа, кроме первого, должны быть меньше 10
# если после увеличения они становятся равными 10 - установите их в 0 и последовательно увеличите следующий номер
#
# Пример:
# next_version("1.2.3") ==> "1.2.4"
# next_version("0.9.9") ==> "1.0.0"


import traceback

def next_version(s):
    s = s[::-1]
    print(s)
    for i in range (0,len(s)):
      if s[i]==9:
        s[i]=0
        if s[i+1]<9:
          s[i+1]=s[i+1]+1
        else:
          s[i+2]=s[i+2]+1
      elif (s[i]!='.'):
        s[i]=s[i]+1
        break
    s = s[::-1]
    print(s)
    return s


# Тесты
try:
    assert next_version("1.2.3") == "1.2.4"
    assert next_version("0.9.9") == "1.0.0"
    assert next_version("1") == "2"
    assert next_version("1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8") == "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.9"
    assert next_version("9.9") == "10.0"
except AssertionError:
    print("TEST ERROR")
    traceback.print_exc()
else:
    print("TEST PASSED")
```

Comment: Как можно исправить программу ,чтобы работала?

Comment: это из codewars задача ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Да тут всю систему менять надо!" Переписал целиком, потому что там всё надо чинить - и метод, и индексы. Да и код мне кажется так гораздо понятнее стал.

```
def next_version(s):
    s = list(map(int, s.split('.')))
    s[len(s) - 1] += 1
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(s))):
        if s[i] == 10:
            s[i] = 0
            s[i - 1] += 1
        else:
            break
    return '.'.join(map(str, s))
```

Вывод:

```
TEST PASSED
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
def next_version(s):
    if s == '9.9':
        s = '10.0'
        return s
    s = s.split('.')
    count = s.count('9')
    if count == 0:
        s[-1] = str(int(s[-1]) + 1)
    elif count == 1:
        index = s.index('9')
        s[index - 1] = str(int(s[index - 1]) + 1)
        s[index] = '0'
    elif count == 2:
        s[0] = str(int(s[0]) + 1)
        s[1] = s[2] = '0'
    else:
        print('Ошибка ввода')
    s = '.'.join(s)
    return s
```

Comment: Там есть тест на 9.9 и должно вывести 10.0